# Regex URL Help: Word or Phrase

Tags: python, regex, django, url, django-urls

I am an absolute noob at regex (I kind of know the basics and need to help a word, or a phrase. If it is a phrase, then separate each word with a hyphen - :

This is my current regex, which only matches one word:

```
r'^streams/search/(?P<stream_query>\w+)/$
```

The ?P just allows the URL to take a parameter.

Extra note: I am using python re module with the Django urls.py

Any suggestions?

Here are some examples:

```
game
gsl
starcraft-2014
final-fantasy-iv
word1-word2-word-3
```

---

Updated explanation:
I basically need a regular expression to expand the current one, so inside the same regex, no other one:

```
r'^streams/search/(?P<stream_query>\w+)/$
```

So include the new regex INSIDE this one, where ?P\w+ is any word that Django considers a parameter (and is passed into a function).

URL definition, which includes the regex:
    url(r'^streams/search/(?P\w+)/$', 'stream_search', name='stream_search')

Then, Django passes that parameter into the stream_search function, which takes that parameter:

```
def stream_search(request, stream_query):
    #here I manipulate the stream_query string, ie: removing the hyphens
```

So, once again, I need an re to match a word or phrase, that are passed into the stream_query parameter (or if necessary, a second one).
So, what I want stream_query to have is:

```
word1
```

or
    word1-word2-word3

Comment: Could you give an example of the two cases you are trying to match?

Comment: I am not sure what you want. I assume you want the regex for a word and a phrase as given. I would suggest "[a-z]+" for a word and [a-z\-] for words separated by hypen

Comment: @Darwin Just added a few examples

Comment: @alexcons Can you provide examples with the whole url?

Comment: @Darwin **example.com/streams/search/rocket-league-word3-word4** or **example.com/streams/search/word1**

Comment: @alexcons You need a `string` to run a `regex` on. What are these `strings` you will be running the `regex` on? Your updated question almost sounds like you are trying to embed a `regex` in a `url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you might not have to use regexs at all.

Based on your example:

```
example.com/streams/search/rocket-league-fsdfs-fsdfs
```

It seems that the term you want to deal with is always found after the last `/`. So you can `rsplit` and then check for `-`. Here is an example:

```
url = "example.com/streams/search/rocket-league-fsdfs-fsdfs"
result = url.rsplit("/", 1)[-1]
#result = ["example.com/streams/search", "rocket-league-fsdfs-fsdfs"]
if "-" in result:
    #do whatever you want with the string
else:
    #do whatever you want with the string
```

or a regex that would match either `word` or `word-word-word` would be: `[\w-]+`

Comment: The problem is, Django requires a parameter first, in this case **rocket-league-sdfd-fdsds** or **word1**, and then I can use the query as a reformatted string.  So, I get rocket-league-fdsf-fsds in THAT format so I do not get a 404 error, and then I can remove the hyphens or do whatever I want

Comment: @alexcons Can you expand your question to give a full example of what you need? I don't use django so I don't know what you mean by "requires a parameter first".

Comment: @alexcons If you are going to run a regex on something you will need access to the url as a string. Since you want to use regex I am assuming you have access to the url as a string so you can apply my example. If my example doesn't work for your situation you need to describe with details why it won't work so I can update it.

Comment: No, I do not have access to the string, because Django deals with with the regex. Django checks if, the parameter you type into the url matches the regex. So, if /streams/search/QUERY, if QUERY matches the regex in the url definition, then it will run the page, else, I will obtain a 404 error. That is why, right now, my regex on accepts one word, so I whenever I type in more than a word, I get a 404

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83001/discussion-between-alex-cons-and-darwin).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import re
str = "http://example.com/something?id=123&action=yes"
regex = "(query\d+)=(\w+)"
re.findall(regex, str)
```

You can also use Python's urlparse library,

```
from urlparse import url parse
urlparse = urlparse("http://example.com/something?id=123&action=yes")
```

Just call `url parse` to return

```
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='example.com', path='/something', params='', query='id=123&action=yes', fragment='')
```

[image: profile for 74U n3U7r1no at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

Comment: How would I implement this into the URL I provided? I am an absolute beginner with regex

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, you are trying to grab the url's parameters which means that "(query\d+)=(\w+)" which return values after = and before &